# How can I limit a site's access to LAN users only in IIS 5.1?

Tags: security, iis, web-server

I want to limit a site's access to connections from the LAN only. How can I do this?

When I go to the **Directory Security** tab of the website, it looks like I need to use **IP address and domain name restrictions**, however the edit button is disabled. I then checked the help and saw that it says:

> (This feature is only available for Windows 2000 Server installations.)

So are there any easy alternatives to doing this on Windows XP? Is it enough to simply make sure that my router isn't allowing port 80 to come in to IIS?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that only computers in your network can access port 80 on a computer also within your network, then make sure the router you're using isn't forwarding port 80 to that computer.